# Running Java Application with ASP.NET Web API in an Azure Web Site

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing an **ASP.NET Web API** that needs a particular **3rd party Java application** to run constantly on the *same machine* to execute some methods.

For deploying in Azure - I guess I can install Java on a **VM** and then manually install and configure the Java application, my Web API, SQL Server and so on..

Is there an easier way?

For example, using the **Azure Web Sites** to run the Web API with Java pre-installed and somehow install the Java application (via code?) and run it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering, have you thought about using SingalR?  Assuming you're using .NET 4 or 4.5.

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm using .NET 4.5 but I don't understand how SignalR can help with this situation.

Comment: You can replace Java with SignalR, which I think would make it easier.  However maybe I didn't understand the question?

Comment: I'm using a 3rd party Java application, I can't change it - I must use it.

Comment: Ok, I missed that part in the question.